# Storing large number of objects in list?

Tags: java, memory

I have a three million rows in a database and I need to get all the values in a table as object and operate on those objects ? what is the best possible solution ?

Comment: use a cache and get some values, operator on those while you are getting your next set of values, and repeat.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686894/tuning-collection-to-hold-large-number-of-objects

Comment: @Clcto can you please explain more about how to do the cacheing ?

Comment: Caching is good idea. Read 1000 rows, use them, read next 1000 rows, use these 2nd 1000 rows, and so on. This is the main idea of caching, I guess, very simply put.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to not load all of them.
Why would need to load them all and operate on them?
Maybe you can do a SP (stored procedure) and work on these rows on the DB server.
If you still need to load them all, try to not load all columns of these rows.
Maybe you can use something like paging (if that is applicable to your case).

My answer is maybe too general but so is your question.

Comment: I cannot run any stored procedures on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said, don't load them all. Instead, use an iterator, like a database cursor (`ResultSet` for the rows in a SQL query) to keep track of your place in the data. For any more specific answer, you'll need to give more detail, but you should also consider whether you can use SQL aggregation functions (`COUNT`, `GROUP BY`, etc.) to reduce the number of rows your application needs to process.